# How come js calculating its(10000000000000000000000000000) length as 5?

Tags: javascript

I really am not understanding how javascript is calculating its length as 5 and whatever no. i append to it, it still shows 5? What mystery am i missing?? Here is the codepen.

```js
var length = Math.floor(10000000000000000000000000000).toString().length;
document.getElementById('length').innerText = length;
```

```html
<h2>Lenght Is </h2>
<h3 id="length"></h3>
```

Edit:
Today I look back to this question I asked and feel stupid. Well everyone is a beginner at some point

Comment: `Math.floor(10000000000000000000000000000).toString() === '1e+28'`, the length of 5 seems to be correct. What did you expect to get?

Comment: It's not `Math.floor`, rather it's a standard way how big [numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type) are represented in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Math.floor(10000000000000000000000000000).toString() 
// 1e+28
```

so it length is 5 is correct

Answer (score 0):

Its evaluated as "1e+28" which is 5 character long

Answer (score 0):

If you try just `toString()` you will see that it returns `1e+21` and therefore `length` is 5

Comment: Don't you mean 1e28?

Comment: yes, of course... 21 is the shortest number that is represented in scientific notation, though. so, 1e+21 is the smallest number that will produce the length of 5

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, `10000000000000000000000000000 == 1e+28`

If you are working with larger ints you should use `BigInt(10000000000000000000000000000) == 9999999999999999583119736832` but you will have to take care to ensure that you are managing the rounding effects of Javascript.

You should look at using some lib's such as `Math.js` to better handle larger calculations.